# How to connect text in apostrophes with string from variable in matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, arguments

I would like to connect  the string saved in "odpoved" with the '*.' and than use the string saved in format as argument in saving.

```
odpoved = questdlg('V akom formáte chcete súbor uložiť?', ...
    'Uložiť vo formáte', ...
    'png','jpg','bmp','bmp');
format = '*.' + odpoved;

[FileName, PathName] = uiputfile('*', 'Save As'); 
Name = fullfile(PathName,FileName);
if (Name ~= 0)
    imwrite(edit_obrazok, Name, textscan(format,'%s'));
end
```

Comment: `'` is a `char` array, `"` is a string. `char` arrays do not support concatenation with `+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other option is to concatenate the two char arrays:

```
format = [ '*.' , odpoved ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the ' with ", as suggested by excaza did the trick.